# Firewalld: Error: Invalid_Zone

Tags: centos, filesystems, security, firewall, firewalld

I got some error I can not solve while setting up a default zone in firewalld.  I added the interface with

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --change-interface=ens3
```

and then I saw the default public zone active.

so then I `firewall-cmd --reload`

*error: Command_failed: 'usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): line 4: Rule_Replace faaled (no Such file or directory: rule in chain INPUT"

so ip6tables-restore is trying to do something upon restart of firewalld. Yet when I "iptables -L" I get "bash: iptables: command not found.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

*Error: Invalid_zone*

But the zone showed moments ago...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CentOS 8, you might want to know that RHEL (and so also CentOS) is migrating from iptables to nftables. In RHEL/CentOS 8, it means `firewalld` is actually using nftables, while the old `iptables` and `ip6tables` packages are still available if you need to go back to iptables.

Try `nft list ruleset` to see the zone rules created by `firewalld`, and think twice before having both `ip[6]tables-restore` and `firewalld` in use at the same time.